# How to Suprress a Group Header and Display It Upon Group Drilldown?

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm using Crystal Reports XI to render data from a SQL Stored Procedure.  I have created a group in Crystal and have set several summarization metrics for the group.  There are half a dozen fields that need to be displayed for each record in a given group.  I want to display my summary headers when the group details are hidden and display my detail headers when the user drills down into a group.

I've created two Group Headers.  The first contains the headers to display in summary and the second contains headers to display on drilldown.  How do I ensure that Group Header B is suppressed until the user drills into the group details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I have done in the past is in the section expert or format object, use the X-2 beside the Suppress option.  Then enter the formula DrillDownGroupLevel = 0, DrillDownGroupLevel = 1, etc.  The number represents how far you are drilling down before it shows up.